Solving functional analysis problems by using Algebraic geometry
I am thinking about some open problems in nonlinear functional analysis and I just wanted to know if there are any problems that have been solved by using Algebraic geometry techniques in these fields.

Not an answer, hence only a comment: probably not exactly what you are having in mind, but do Vinogradov's diffieties (see also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diffiety) count? That aside, it's usually the other way around: methods from functional analysis help with problems in Algebraic Geometry.
